# C2280 Error when i run the program

Tags: c++

I had been encounter the error c2280 after I run my program and i can't identify where is the problem. would anyone advice me on this issue?
    transaction.h
    #ifndef TRANSACTION_H
    #define TRANSACTION_H

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

class Transaction
{
public:
    Transaction(string input);
    string getDate();
    string getTime();
    string getCondition();
    float getPrice();
    float getValue();
    int getVolume();
    void find_and_replace(string& source, string const& find, string const& replace);

private:
    ostringstream date;
    ostringstream time;
    string condition;
    float price, value;
    int volume, day, month, year, hour, minute;
};

Transaction::Transaction(string input) {

    find_and_replace(input, "/", " ");
    find_and_replace(input, ":", " ");
    find_and_replace(input, "", " ");
    stringstream tranStream(input);
    tranStream >> day;
    tranStream >> month;
    tranStream >> year;
    tranStream >> hour;
    tranStream >> minute;
    tranStream >> price;
    tranStream >> volume;
    tranStream >> value;
    tranStream >> condition;

}

string Transaction::getDate() {
    date << day << '/' << month << '/' << year;

    return date.str();
}

string Transaction::getTime() {
    string PlusZero;
    if (minute < 10) {
        PlusZero = "" + to_string(minute);
        time << hour << ':' << PlusZero;
    }
    else {

        time << hour << ':' << minute;
    }
    return time.str();
}

float Transaction::getPrice() {
    return price;
}

int Transaction::getVolume() {
    return volume;
 }

float Transaction::getValue() {
    return value;
}

string Transaction::getCondition() {
    return condition;

}

void Transaction::find_and_replace(string& source, string const& find, string const& replace)
{
    for (string::size_type i = 0; (i = source.find(find, i)) != string::npos;)
    {
        source.replace(i, find.length(), replace);
        i += replace.length();
    }
}

#endif // !TRANSACTION_H

mainmenu.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Transaction.h"

using namespace std;

void printStock(vector<Transaction> t, int i) {
    cout << "Date :" << t.at(i).getDate << endl;
    cout << "Time :" << t.at(i).getTime() << endl;
    cout << "Price : " << t.at(i).getPrice() << endl;
    cout << "Volume : " << t.at(i).getVolume() << endl;
    cout << "Value : " << t.at(i).getValue() << endl;
    cout << "Condition: " << t.at(i).getCondition() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}


int main() {
    string menu;

    vector<Transaction> TransList;
    string a = "24/07/2015 17:00,6,67889,407334,CT";
    string b = "24/07/2015 17:01,5.8,144,835.2,XT";
    string c = "24/07/2015 17:04,0,0,0,CTXT";
    string d = "24/07/2015 17:10,5.78,1203,6953.34,CT";

    TransList.push_back(a);
    TransList.push_back(b);
    TransList.push_back(c);
    TransList.push_back(d);



    for (int i = 0; i < TransList.size(); i++) {
    printStock(TransList, i);
    }

    cin >> menu;
    return 0;
}
```

I was suspecting that it is the problem at the vector as this problem didn't appear when I disabled the vector and while check on the result of each string.
But I will need a vector to store the data read for parsing purpose.
Thank You All!

Answer (score 0):

The `ostringstream` is not allowed to copy, and you have inside of your class twice, so you can't copy this class without your own copy constructor. However you can change:
`void printStock(vector<Transaction> t, int i) {`
to
`void printStock(vector<Transaction> & t, int i) {` 
and pass vector by reference not by copy.

Maybe consider using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` to construct Transaction directly inside of vector. Using push_back creates temporary object and then uses move constructor to add it into the vector.

And another mistake is here:
`cout << "Date :" << t.at(i).getDate << endl;` it should be getDate() not just getDate

Comment: Hi KIIV, Thank you for the great help! I tried to change the ostringstream and passing the vector reference and now, there is no error found!